# angular 2 promises in sqlite communication

Tags: angular, sqlite, typescript

I am implementing an Angular 2 Sqlite communication through 3 layers. I got issues with promises in return an tried to resolve like below.

**1.Outer Service(routerService.ts)**

```
routerService(reqObject): Observable<any> {
     this.dbServiceProvider.dbService(reqObject).subscribe(dbServiceResponse => {
            console.log("data fetched", dbServiceResponse);
     });
}
```

**2. dbService.ts**

```
    dbService(requestObj): Observable<any> {
    let tableSchema: any[] = [];
      this.databaseprovider.getTableInfo(requestObj.tableName).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.rows.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
            tableSchema.push(data.rows.item(i).name);
          }
        }
        console.log(tableSchema);
        requestObj['tableSchema'] = tableSchema;
        return requestObj;
      })
```

**3. database.ts**

```
     //Getting column Names
      getTableInfo(tbl): Observable<any> {
        let query = 'PRAGMA table_info(' + tbl + ');';
         return Observable.of(this.database.executeSql(query, [])).map(data => {
          console.log("got Pragma", data);//here i am getting object with Zone values
          return data;
        }, err => {
          console.log('Error: ', err);
          return err;
        });
      }
```

Here if I am not using `Observable.of()` its not waiting for the sql execution.
And now the problem is its returning an object with 'zone values'. So i am unable to retrieve data from the returned object.

I am looking for a solution for promises or observable to execute these 3 services.

Comment: IS the sqlite also on the client side as the angular in the browser?

Comment: Yes, SqLite is used in client side to sore data and we will sync this data to server side database

Answer (score 0):

```
async getTableInfo(tbl): Observable<any> {
    let query = 'PRAGMA table_info(' + tbl + ');';
    let res = <any>await this.database.executeSql(query, []);
    if (res.rows.item(0))
        return of(res.rows.item(0))
    else of([])
}
```

Note: I'm not catching the error here.